# embed double quoted string in groovy

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy

I want to embed following command in groovy.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query "Reservations[].Instances[].{Name: Tags[?Key == 'Name'].Value|[0]}"
```

but nothing is working I tried escaping single quotes, double quotes in the main command but still groovy stuff not working.

My final groovy script is as shown below

```
def command = "aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query \"Reservations[].Instances[].{Name: Tags[?Key == \'Name\'].Value|[0]}\" "
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              
def instances = proc.in.text.readLines()
return instances
```

Comment: this solution does not solve my problem.

Comment: Works here. `['aws', 'ec2', 'describe-instances', '--output', 'text', '--query', "Reservations[].Instances[].{Name: Tags[?Key == 'Name'].Value|[0]}"]`.

Comment: I do not know what to say. You made my day. I also tried the same but something I was missing with quotes. Thanks